# Why should we multiply delta by gradient instead of division, during backpropagation of activation function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

Why should we multpiply `delta` by `gradient` instead of `division`, during backpropagation of activation function?

For example, as known: ReLU-activation with `slope=0.1`:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Leaky_ReLUs

`if(x > 0) y = x; else y = x * 0.1`

So:

- **forward** (inference): `if(x > 0) y = x; else y = x * 0.1;`  https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/04ab089db018a292ae48d51732dd6c66766b36b6/src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cpp#L16-L17
- **backward** (backpropagation): `if(x > 0) gradient = 1; else gradient = 0.1;` and then `new_delta = delta * gradient` - so this is the same formula as in forward `if(delta > 0) new_delta = x; else new_delta = delta * 0.1;`  https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/04ab089db018a292ae48d51732dd6c66766b36b6/src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cpp#L32-L33

---

Also, as known `gradient = dY / dX`

During gradient descent we propagate `delta` through `y = ReLU(x)` activation function, i.e. finaly we want to change output `y` of ReLU-function by this value `delta = dY`.

For this we should change `x` by `dX`, i.e. `dX = dY / gradient`

But in all frameworks, include Caffe, we multiply it by gradient instead of division,

i.e. `dX = dY * gradient`

Why we multpiply `delta` by `gradient` instead of `division`, during backpropagation through activation function?

---

[image]

---

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry but your math is all wrong, you are not applying the chain rule at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find the math for back-propagation so i'll stick to the intuition for now.

The first thing that you got wrong is that we are not trying to change X, in fact we have no control over X which is the networks input. What we are trying to change is W (the weights).

But why do we multiply delta by gradient of activation? in back-propagation we want to calculate for a weight W_ij, how much this weight has had to do with the error produced (dE/dW_ij) so we can know how to correct each weight. The delta_ij is an indicator of how much the input to the neuron j (the neuron at the end of W_ij) has contributed to the error. The activation function for neuron j is then applied to its input, the bigger the derivative of this function, the less we have to change the input to reduce the error. In other words the activation functions derivative is proportionate to contribution of W_ij to the error produced.

studying the math behind BP also helps, so [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/backpropagation/) is a mathematical explanation.